# Neural network: what is the order of parameter updates in this case?

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, torch

Input: `x, target`

Network:

```
P = torch.ones(x.shape)
gamma = 1
mask = W*x + b1 
mask_x = mask*x
y = mask_x*P
y = W2*x + b2
P = (gamma - mask_x)*P
loss = CrossEntropy(y,target)
```

How does parameter `P` update in this case? I seem that in loss backward, `P` will update by gradient, however, here, I also update `P` by `P = (gamma - mask_x)*P`. I'm confused about the order of parameter's update.

eg.
Which is correct?

```
P = P + lr*grad_p
mask_x = mask_x + lr*grad_m
P = (gamma -mask_x)*P
```

Or

```
P = (gamma -mask_x)*P
P = P + lr*grad_p
mask_x = mask_x + lr*grad_m
```

`grad_m` and `grad_p` are the gradient of parameter `mask_x` and `P` respectively.

Comment: Are you confused by the math? What is the question?

Comment: Please explain what you are doing there!